# Get your position in "tag-league" (top x%)

Tags: discussion, tags, design, profile-page, reputation-leagues

There is a "top users" list that you see for each tag [python](/questions/tagged/python) or [numpy](/questions/tagged/numpy) etc. This also is used to give a "top n%" to the user on their developer page.

[image]

My question is since the next step in this league is "Top 1%", it's not apparent how far I am from that milestone.

So, is there a way I can perhaps see/estimate how much more score is needed to get into the "Top 1%" or "Top 5%" of a tag as of date?

---

**EDIT:** I found a way to get the # rank but figuring out the exact "top x%"

[image]

Comment: Since there is already a tag for [developer-story](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bdeveloper-story%5D+top) on MSO, and no such tag here, I can't help but think that this question (as worded) is applicable to one site only; the Developer Story feature on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to [How does "TOP 10%" work in the Developer Story?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/355153/4751173), [this SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/50844/what-percentile-am-i-in-for-a-given-tag) calculates the top x% for any given user and tag. It says you're in the top 3% (see below); you'll have to [fork](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/fork/50844) the query to find out what score exactly is needed to get into the top 1%.

[image]

Comment: For posterity, just adding the [direct link to the script](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/50844/what-percentile-am-i-in-for-a-given-tag) in the comments.

Comment: You're welcome. FWIW, the direct link to the script is already in the body of the answer – those are two separate links in the first line.

Comment: Hi one question here, I do see that the query you shared shows that for the tag: `machine-learning`, my percentile is `3%`, but on my developer page, it shows I am still `top 10%` and not `top 5%`. Is there a difference in this and what the query is calculating?

Comment: Same is the case with `neural-network` tag and `scikit-learn` tag.

Comment: Hmm ... typical. I'm not actually sure what the actual formula *is* (and whether it's known at all). Since the Developer Story is specific to [Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/), the answer can likely be found there.